# Find the letters that complete these five patterns

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

Complete the last line in each of the following five series:

Puzzle 1:

```
"Using" is E
"Desist" is I
"Visits" is E
"Design" is ???
```

Puzzle 2:

```
"Asia" is H
"Cuffs" is S
"Ender" is I
"Redness" is F
"Fuchsia" is ???
```

Puzzle 3 (advanced):

```
"Pro-tem" and "row" are H
"Ties" is K
"Cohesion" is A
"Casino" is E
"Hocks" is either a word, name, ??? or ???
```

Puzzle 4:

```
"Gross" is W or R
"Assign" is S
"Amassing" is E
"Design" is S
"Amassing" is S
"Arrows" is ??? or ???
```

Puzzle 5:

```
"Edna" is I
"Slang" is X
"Siege" is E
"Basin" is X
"Sin" is X
"Sin" is A
"Besiege" is X
"Signals" is ??? and ???
```

First person to solve all five gets the win.

Hint:

> Each ??? stands for a single letter of the English alphabet.

Hint #2:

> The puzzles are not related to one another, except that they are all based on the same principle.  If you solve any one, you will rapidly solve all the others.

Hint #3, a quite cryptic one:

> The very first parts of vague solutions can decode nothing: that's the core of these puzzles.

Hint #4, a more obvious one:

> **You want another hint?!** Nag! Go botanist first, arse ulcer! O my! More clues? Rats! Rifts in a toboggan!

Comment: Random thoughts: The letters seem to suggest Morse code (E,I,S,H are dot-only characters) except for F.  They also possess symmetry, again except for F.

Comment: I added a third, even longer puzzle, so I'm hopeful that it will be solved today.

Comment: I think this is an example of there not being enough data to come to a unique conclusion. There are four possible answers below, and I thought of a few more. There are just too many patterns that can make three words yield the letters E, I, and E. More data is needed to reduce the number of possible patterns.

Comment: @BmyGuest Thanks for giving these puzzles a second look. I assure you there's nothing random about these. They are painstakingly constructed.

Comment: @Bachrach44 Remember that all these puzzles follow the same pattern. If you think you might have more success with the 8-line puzzle, look closely at that one. Personally, I think the shortest one is easiest.

Comment: The puzzle idea is indeed great (and painstakingly constructed), but I *still* think your original posting was not. It only became *good* after adding the longer puzzles to it. I think this puzzle *as a whole* is much better. Don't call it "puzzle 1...5" have it **the puzzle** with part 1 to 5. This way, all alternative solutions drop out and your intended one *becomes* the only one.

Comment: @MattMalone Just hope you can still *think*  sentences which are not palindromes :c) I'm going to remove a couple of the comments in this section, a) as they are not any longer relevant with the edits, b) to have things shorter & cleaner, c) avoid spoilers. BTW, I think I *would* remove the 4th hint now...

Comment: @BmyGuest Remove it?  When am I going to have another chance to work "arse ulcer" into a puzzle?

Comment: Just switched my downvote to an upvote. Feedback: Cool puzzle, but it just needed more data points from the get go.

Comment: This puzzle is currently tied for 2nd best puzzle of 2014. :)  http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/best-puzzles-of-2014

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Brilliant puzzle.

Puzzle 1:

> U

Puzzle 2:

> A

Puzzle 3:

> T or P

Puzzle 4:

> S or G

Puzzle 5:

> I and E

Explanation:

> They are palindromes, and every word is part of the palindrome too.

Individual solutions

> The beginning, middle and end of the palindrome have been bolded:
> **u**sing is e desist is i **v**isits is e design is **U**
> **a**sia is h cuffs is s ender i**s** i redness is f fuchsia is **A**
> **p**ro-**t**em and row are h ties is k cohesion is a **c**asino is e hocks is either a word, name, **T** or **P**
> **g**ro**s**s is w or r assign is s amassing is e **d**esign is s amassing is s arrows is **S** or **G**
> **e**dna **i**s i slang is x siege is e basin is x si**n** is x sin is a besiege is x si gnals is **I** and **E**

Comment: Very close!!! But no unscrambling is required. You're almost there!

Comment: Fixed, and I was right to upvote, and vote to reopen.

Comment: And in case anyone didn't understand weird hint #3: The very first parts of "vague solutions can decode nothing" means the first letters of those words: V, S, C, D and N. That's the core of these puzzles, means that these are the central letters of the palindromes. I see you've already highlighted those, so you must have figured that out.

Comment: Hint 4 itself is a palindrome, except for the bold part.

Answer (score 16):

The letter is

> I

because you

> count the number of letters of the word that are also in your username, "Matt Malone"

which gives

> `"Using"  is 1 (n)
>  "Desist" is 2 (te)
>  "Visits" is 1 (t)
>  "Design" is 2 (ne)`

and then

> take the letter that consists of that many dots in Morse code (`e=.`, `i=..`, `s=...`, `h=....`).

Comment: The idea of people reading my name over and over, carefully counting each letter, is great for my ego but it won't help you solve this puzzle.

Comment: @MattMalone The problem is that this is 100% plausible, and there's nothing in the question to refute this theory.

Comment: So wonderfully obscure and random while still perfectly plausible. I love this answer! @MattMalone I think xnor is just proofing by example that your question needs editing to be a valuable and not random puzzle. Can you add a (much) larger series? Or at her conditions which make the answer uniquely defined?

Comment: @BmyGuest Trust me. There is precisely one answer that fits. Once you see it you'll agree. It would be very difficult to make the series longer. I assure you that it's quite long enough already.

Comment: @MattMalone *" There is precisely one answer that fits."* What's wrong with this answer besides it not matching your own method?

Comment: This answer, while quite clever, is ad hoc. The puzzle is carefully and precisely written. There is one undeniably correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's the letter

> I

The pattern is that it's the second letter of the word immediately following it.

> `"Using"  is E
>  "Desist" is I
>  "Visits" is E
>  "Design" is ???`

which give the answer because

> the next word is "H**i**nt".

Alternatively, the answer could be

> S

if you

> wrap around back to "U**s**ing".

Comment: Clever, using "Hint"! I like it! But I'm afraid that's not it.

Answer (score 5):

Answer;

> I

Explanation;

> The words having nothing to do with it, the pattern is E, I, E, I...

---

**Alternatively...**

> The answer is "one letter"

Why?

> You told us in the hint!

---

**Or maybe...**

> I

Because...

> Whichever letter comes first in the word, is the opposite (I is E, E Is I)
>  "Us**i**ng" is E
>  "D**e**sist" is I
>  "V**i**sits" is E
>  "D**e**sign" is I

---

**Perhaps it's...**

> I

A new idea why;

> If the first *i* in the word is the 4th letter it's I else, it's E

---

Maybe it's...

> I

Reasoning;

> If the word contains an E the answer is I, else it's E

Comment: Nice try! But no.

Comment: I was just going to post that too, war spying.

Comment: Sorry, you're still not there yet. When you see it, it will be strikingly, clearly the right answer.

Comment: @warspyking I did, sorry. Auto spellcheck isn't always useful :-)

Comment: @warspyking Not yet.  But I bet someone gets it soon.

Comment: Did you read the newest hints?

Comment: @warspyking Even the very last hint?  You don't notice anything unusual?  Nothing fishy about it?